# how to redirect to another page if file exist in root?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make a script to put on all my pages on my site saying if *so and so* file exist in the root directory ("/") it will auto redirect to it and if the file isn't there it does nothing.

I'm using this so i can set up a maintenance mode for the site so i can take it down while im working on it. I already have made the maintenance page, I just don't know how to set up the script. The file name is `maintenance.html` and I only want it to be in the root file. I don't want to have to upload it to every directory to take the site down.

The file url would be `http://domain.tld/maintenance.html` and the script would go if the file is there and redirect to that file else if it's not there don't redirect.
I know the redirect code is (in HTML)

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://domain.tld">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of redirection rules for your webserver is what you need, methinks. If you're running Apache, `mod_rewrite` is the magic word, if you're running something else, well, then, I wouldn't know the magic word, but something similar exists for most servers, if not all.

But, using Apache's brilliant `mod_rewrite`, to redirect ALL traffic to a set page or address, e.g. during maintenance, is as simple as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Use mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# If you want, you can exclude yourself by adding a condition for the redirection,
# i.e. if the RewriteCond matches, proceed with the RewriteRule
# This statement checks that the IP of the client isn't 123.456.789.012
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !123.456.789.012

# Redirect all traffic to /maintenance.html with a "307 Temporary Redirect",
# except traffic to the maintenance page.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=307,L]

</IfModule>
```

Where should these instructions be, you ask? Well, since it's a temporary thing, the most logical would be in a `.htaccess` file in your webroot. But it's also possible to include the same in your servers/virtualhosts global configuration, which for a permanent ruleset would make sense from an optimization aspect.

To disable the redirection, it's enough to comment out either the `RewriteEngine on` statement, or the `RedirectRule` statement. You could also rename your `.htaccess` to something else or delete it.

Comment: its also taking out my maintenance page and i allow all cookies
The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: @Kyle: Ah, yes. I forgot to add a condition for the "base case" where no redirection shall take place. That happens more often than not, but luckily it's a familiar error, so I know how to fix it. Please, take a look at the edited code snippet for relief.

Comment: thanks btw how would i do it if they files are in another directory than root
example i want to redirect it to the same file but i have it stored in another directory
or i want to allow some other pages not to be taken down that are in other directory
or make it not block an entire directory like /forums and everything in it

Comment: You adjust the paths where appropriate and use additional `RewriteCond` statements respectively. Look up `mod_rewrite` for more information. There's plenty of guides and howtos on the internet, as well as loads of questions on the topic here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RedirectPermanent / /maintenance.html
RedirectPermanent /page2.html /maintenance.html
RedirectPermanent /anotherpage.html /maintenance.html
```

And so on. So just do this for each page of your site, on a new line for each.

This will redirect each of your pages right away to the maintenance page.

.htaccess is the best way to do it in my opinion. (better than JavaScript)

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

To use it, first you put:

`RedirectPermanent`

And then a space and then the page you want to redirect to the maintenance page:

`/page.html`

And then another space and then the page you want to redirect to:

`/maintenance.html`

So, all together, here's an example:

```
RedirectPermanent /page.html /maintenance.html
```

**Note the space in between *RedirectPermanent*, the *page redirecting from* and the page redirecting to.**

The way it works, well I don't know. This isn't a script, it's a .htaccess file code.

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, all you have to do is create a file called `.htaccess` (make sure the `.` is in there) and then upload it to your root directory. (where you upload all of the rest of your pages.)

Comment: umm do u mind explaining how the script works so i can be able to edit it later on if i need to

Comment: i get this when i use this
500 Internal Service Error
You have reached this page due to a malfunctioning .htaccess file.

Comment: Um, did you put each one on it's own line? It did that to me before to. But I got it to work on my site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if(file_exists('/file.php'))
{
   //do something if file exists
}
```

Comment: works up to a point if file is their it redirects but it also redirects if file isn't their

Answer (score 2):

The better way would be the put a .htaccess named file in your root folder with the following content:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
```

This redirects automatically to this page, if the called page is not existing.

Comment: also why 404 404 would be cant be found page and im just trying to take the site offline with out removing anything from the site other than updating the pages

Answer (score 1):

It's not very efficient to write your own server-side script to check for a file when your webserver can do it for you. Use Apache's mod_rewrite capability in an .htaccess file; you'll enable (i.e. uncomment) your rewrite rules when you want to put your page in maintenance mode. Doing it this way would also allow you to access the website while you work on it if you put in a rule to allow access from your own IP.

If this is free hosting -- which it seems like it is -- then you may not be able to do this, but I don't see why it would be a major issue to do it. Most webserver software has some sort of rewrite function, and this is a fairly trivial rewrite.

Alternatively you could use a quick-and-dirty bit of Javascript similar to this (might not be exactly this):
    `<script type="text/javascript">location = www.yoursite.com/maintenance.html;</script>`

It'd be better to use rewrites, though.

Comment: I agree, especially because javascript doesn't work if it is disabled in the browser

Comment: its not doing anything i used the code u gave me but i changed the url
also idk how to do .htaccess that's why im doing it all manually
idk if it has some sort of rewrite function yes its a free hosting but i have to do all the site coding on my comp and upload throw ftp

Comment: also i wasn't thing of java to much because i was thinking of making a mobile version of my websites so people can view them on their phones

Comment: Java and JavaScript are by no means the same thing.

Comment: they are to me 8P
if its a javascript then it uses java

Comment: No, it doesn't. They are not the same language. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470971/Java-vs-JavaScript.htm